# Cursor flickers between pointer and arrow

Tags: html, css

Currently making a website which contains a table, of set height, whose rows populate and depopulate over time. On each row I have `:hover { cursor: pointer; }`, but it seems that when I move it between the rows it flickers between the pointer and the normal mouse arrow. I've also noticed this on other websites as well, I wasn't sure if this was a known issue or if there was anything that can be done about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to put your table inside a div and then make the whole div have a `cursor: pointer` you also don't need to have `cursor: pointer` on the `:hover` pseudo class either.

Comment: You were right, I just had to move `cursor: pointer` from :hover to the plain class and it works like a charm. Nice smooth cursor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to try if your custom CSS cursors flicker back and forth to the default mouse arrow: check to see if Photoshop is open.

Photoshop can affect the mouse cursor in other applications; try quitting Photoshop to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: YES! that was happening to me. I spent four hours trying to understand why my cursors are flickering, CSS is ignored and not switching the cursor to "pointer". Turns out all I had to do was close photoshop... to make CHROME work again....  someone in Adobe is doing a very ugly, very low-level cursor manipulation and the fact one process can affect a totally separate process in such a destructive manner -- is a FAIL for Apple and MacOs.

Comment: I just had the same problem. It was only messing up my cursor on MY website though! This is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hover state for the entire table which will prevent that behavior:

```
table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Alternatively, eliminate the tiny space between cells (which is where the cursor switch is occuring):

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would do the former, but the table has a set height and I only want `cursor: pointer` where there are rows not all over the entire thing ya know. The second idea didn't work for me either, still experiencing the flickering.

Comment: Found the issue, I didn't need the pointer on :hover, that was causing the problem.